# Is there a way to add a different action on the second click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code is this:

```
$('.how-we-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.how-we-menu > ul').slideDown();
  $('.under').on('click', function() {
    $('.under > ul').slideDown();
  })
  $('.over').on('click', function() {
    $('.over > ul').slideDown();
  })
  $('.ar').on('click', function() {
    $('.ar > ul').slideDown();
  })
  $('.fc').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

I am trying to avoid slide toggle because it affects another element and slides both of them up so I want to make each element work individually. So when you click ".fc > ul" once it slides down and when you click again it slides up.

I hope this makes sense thanks!

Comment: This code will also affect all the elements that match the selector. If you want to only affect this element, use `$(this)` in the function.

Comment: Better if you provide the sample HTML content of `.how-we-menu`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` in the function so it only affects the element you clicked on.

```
$('.fc').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

And all the event handlers should be at top level, not inside another event handler. Since they all do the same thing, you can bind them all at once.

```js
$('.how-we-menu, .under, .over, .ar, .fc').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Don't try to put code in a comment. Edit the question and create a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Don't put event handlers inside other event handlers.

Comment: How should I change it then ?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, It works but  since ".how-we-menu" is the parent and it keeps toggle sliding up and hiding the rest of the classes whenever I click them.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp